# "Not a git repository" message on startup

Tags: ssh, startup, git

When I log-in to my Ubuntu server via ssh, I get the following message:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 2.6.32-042stab094.7 x86_64)

* Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
Last login: Thu Jan 26 02:55:43 2017 from 255.255.255.255
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

First part is quite usual. But why I get that "Not a git repository" message? How can I know what the process run (and which) git command?

Comment: Do you also get the error when running `bash -l`?

Comment: What do you have in your `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: Anything in / etc/profile or profile.d?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the problem was the following alias in my `.zshrc`:

```bsh
alias git-clear="git branch -d $(git branch --merged)"
```

where I replaced double quotes with single ones, and everything became ok.

Many thanks to @muru and @Jakuje for helping me to figure that out!

Comment: Glad you fixed it! Please mark your answer as the correct one.